# Trigger Camel Routes in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel, spring-camel

My Default Camel Routes work (Spring DSL) on App Startup. It is a simple route of moving files (as I am a beginner in Camel). However what I want to do is to have the route only trigger in the Controller while a JSP page is launched

For example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) throws Exception {

//In here I want to execute a route not when app loads
}
```

I am not using Spring Boot, I have researched on this topic but I havent found anything

I have in addition tried

```
@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;
```

but it didnt work. I would appreciate the readers help.

I realize we can use autoStartup=false in our xml, I use that, and now the files are not getting triggered through our controller as well. New code for the controller is

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) throws Exception {

        SpringCamelContext camelContext = (SpringCamelContext) applicationContext.getBean("camelContext");

        try {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            camelContext.start();
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Hello2");
            camelContext.stop();
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

and in xml i have

```
    <camel:camelContext  id="camelContext" trace="true" autoStartup="false">
        <camel:route >
            <camel:from uri="file:data/inbox?noop=true" />
            <camel:to uri="file:data/outbox" />
        </camel:route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

Comment: I managed to get this autoStartup working by adding this to the controller code `camelContext.setAutoStartup(true);`

Comment: So your question is answered? If yes please add your comment as the answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this autoStartup working by adding this to the controller code

```
camelContext.setAutoStartup(true);
```